# How to print the child element in XMLusing XPATH

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

Apologises if this is duplicate.
I want to display all the child attributes of  `Employees` 
here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee emplid="1111" type="admin">
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <lastname>Watson</lastname>
        <age>30</age>
        <email>johnwatson@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee emplid="2222" type="admin">
        <firstname>Sherlock</firstname>
        <lastname>Homes</lastname>
        <age>32</age>
        <email>sherlock@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee emplid="3333" type="user">
        <firstname>Jim</firstname>
        <lastname>Moriarty</lastname>
        <age>52</age>
        <email>jim@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee emplid="4444" type="user">
        <firstname>Mycroft</firstname>
        <lastname>Holmes</lastname>
        <age>41</age>
        <email>mycroft@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Here is java class

```
package com.logic.xpath;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Xpath 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        try
        {

            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse( new FileInputStream("c:\\file.xml"));

            /*String xml = ...;
            Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));*/

            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();




//          Print all the employee email whose empid='3333'

            String expression = "/Employees/Employee[@emplid='3333']/email";
            System.out.println(expression);
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
            {
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }

            // Pritnt all the employees firstname
            String expression1 = "/Employees/Employee/firstname";
            System.out.println(expression1);
             nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression1).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
            {
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }

            //Print all the employyees whose emp id is 2222
            String expression3 = "/Employees/Employee[@emplid='2222']";
            System.out.println(expression3);
            Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression3).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
            if(null != node) {
                nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
                for (int i = 0;null!=nodeList && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node nod = nodeList.item(i);
                    if(nod.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                        System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName() + " : " + nod.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                }
            }


            //Print all the employes firstname whose type is ADMIN

            String expression4 = "/Employees/Employee[@type='admin']/firstname";
            System.out.println(expression4);
             nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression4).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }


            //print all employees firstname whoes age is greater than 30
            String expression5 = "/Employees/Employee[age>40]/firstname";
            nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression5).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }


            //print first name of first 2 employee define in the respective element 

            String expression6 = "/Employees/Employee[position() <= 2]/firstname";
             nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression6).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

i want to `display firstname lastname age email`

like `String expression1 = "/Employees/Employee/firstname";` will print the firstname of employee only how to print every thing

Expected output:

```
 firstname=John lastname=Watson age=30 email=johnwatson@sh.com firstname=Sherlock lastname=Homes age=32 email=sherlock@sh.com and so on of every employee
```

Comment: _"all the child attributes of `Employees`"_ -- The `Employees` node has no attributes, only child elements.  Please clarify what you want to do by showing the expected output.

Comment: @JimGarrison Sorry For the ambiguity. I want to print the firstname lastname and age and emial of all the employee

Comment: Show the expected output

Comment: @JimGarrison Output----------

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the expected output. Indent 4 spaces to format as code

Comment: @JimGarrison firstname=John lastname=Watson age=30 email=johnwatson@sh.com firstname=Sherlock lastname=Homes age=32 email=sherlock@sh.com and so on of every employee

Comment: PLEASE [edit] your post and include the information there.

Comment: like here String expression1 = "/Employees/Employee/firstname"; i specify to print the firstname i want to print every element inside the /Employees/Employee/

Comment: I don't think you really need XPath to print all elements of `Employee`, just use smth like StAX parser.

Comment: @MikhailKuchma How to use it ?

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh I've added some sample code as answer

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh `/Employees/Employee/*` should return all child elements of `Employee` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use StAX approach like

```
private final static String xml = <<your big xml>>;

public static void main(String... args) throws XMLStreamException {
    // flag to indicate processing of Employee tag
    boolean isEmployee = false;
    // Flag to indicate processing text data in a tag rather than whitespaces outside tags, 
    // e.g. spaces between brackets
    // <Employee emplid="3333" type="user">[
    //        ]<firstname>Jim</firstname>
    boolean showText = false;
    // current tag name;
    String tagName = "";
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLEventReader reader = xif.createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xml));
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        XMLEvent ev = reader.nextEvent();
        switch (ev.getEventType()) {
        case START_ELEMENT:
            StartElement start = ev.asStartElement();
            tagName = start.getName().getLocalPart();
            if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")) {
                isEmployee = true;
            } else if (isEmployee) {
                showText = true;
            }
            break;
        case CHARACTERS:
            Characters chars = ev.asCharacters();
            if (isEmployee && showText) {
                System.out.println(tagName + " = " + chars.getData());
            }
            break;
        case END_ELEMENT:
            EndElement end = ev.asEndElement();
            if (end.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")) {
                isEmployee = false;
                System.out.println("");
            }
            showText = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It requires Java 6+, further help can be get from JavaDoc and [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with these Xpath to get separate values of each field ,save it any variable to form the entire output

```
//Employee[@emplid]/firstname/text()
//Employee[@emplid]/lastname/text()
//Employee[@emplid]/age/text()
//Employee[@emplid]/email/text()
```

To get all the text use below xpath

```
//Employee[@emplid]//text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution to print all the child elements.

i just change the expression

```
String expression1 = "/Employees/Employee/*";
            System.out.println(expression1);
             nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression1).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
            {
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }
```

Adding `*` make my work